# Не отображаются стили окна в активити

Tags: android, android-studio, listview, android-layout, style

Есть стандартный стиль AppTheme в styles.xml:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

</style>
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_splash</item>
</style>
```

Есть layout с одним customlistview, который заполняется ArayAdapter'ом. 
вот основной layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/lightorange"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="5dp"
android:paddingLeft="5dp"
android:paddingRight="5dp"
android:paddingTop="15dp"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"


tools:context=".vvedenie">

<ListView


    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</ListView>
```

Вот row_item.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
     >
    <TableRow>
     <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"/>

       <TextView
        android:typeface="serif"
        android:id="@+id/txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />

       </TableRow>
       </TableLayout>
```

В итоге в приложении, при запуске отображается только данная таблица, а статус бар полностью бесцветный(белый).
Пробовал в методе onCreate указывать : `setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);`
пробовал указывать в лэйаутах `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"`( манифесте указана тема AppTheme)
Как это исправить?

Comment: Попробуй в качестве родительской темы указать `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` вместо `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`

Comment: вы используете тему без экшенбара, не используете вместо него Toolbar и хотите, чтобы у вас был экшенбар, но чудес не бывает, тем более в таком деле, как программирование - что написал, точно то и получил.

Comment: @Vadik пробовал, результат аналогичный: в лэйауте с листвью как статусбара не было, так и нет. Да, появился экшенбар, но при открытии лэйаута с листвью - он так же отсутствует.

Comment: @pavlofff мне и не нужен экшен бар или тулбар. Меня интересует: почему не отображается статусбар в данном лэйауте.

Comment: Приложите скриншот, чтобы точно понимать, что вы имеете ввиду под _статус бар полностью бесцветный (белый)_. Каким ожидаете видеть статусбар (какого цвета)? Проверьте еще раз, что в манифесте не используется тема SplashTheme (как в теге `application`, так и в теге `activity`), т. к. у этой темы не задан `colorPrimary`, который определяет цвет статус бара.